# how can i show default selected radio button with DLRadiobutton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button, dlradiobutton

when app loads i have to select on option but i want to show default radio button selected when app loads..
I have used this code for showing radio button

```
public func createRadioButton(frame : CGRect, title : String, color : UIColor) -> DLRadioButton {
     radioButton = DLRadioButton(frame: frame);
    radioButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14);
    radioButton.setTitle(title, for: []);
    radioButton.setTitleColor(color, for: []);
    radioButton.iconColor = color;
    radioButton.indicatorColor = color;
    radioButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.left;
    radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.logSelectedButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside);
    self.view.addSubview(radioButton);

    return radioButton;
}

@objc @IBAction public func logSelectedBtn(radioButton : DLRadioButton) {


    if (radioButton.isMultipleSelectionEnabled) {
        for button in radioButton.selectedButtons() {
            print(String(format: "%@ is selected.\n", button.titleLabel!.text!));

        }
    } else {

        hello2 = radioButton.selected()!.titleLabel!.text!
        print(String(format: "%@ is selected.\n", hello2));
    }
}
```

Comment: This question isn't clear.  Is DLRadioButton from some library you are using?  If so then there is probably some API on that class that will let you choose the default selection.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
radioButton.isSelected = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing in the attribute inspector did't work for me, so I added it programatically as follows:

In the ViewDidLoad method:

self.yourRadioButton.isSelected = true

There you go!

[image]